# Create charts for metro application for windows phone 8 OS and Windows 8 OS

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I need to make **metro application** for windows phone 8 os **(WP 8)**. For that, I need to make some **charts/graphs**. How can I create charts? can I use wpf or silverlite for windows phone 8 application? Which is more preferable ?  Can I run same app in WP 8 (for Phone) and windows 8 (PC) **both**, using C#?  I am new in this field. please answer, asap. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/ Also such questions are too broad and are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous third party libraries which will allow you to create charts for both Windows Phone and WinRT.

Please note that Windows Phone and WinRT use different flavours of XAML. This means that sharing UI controls can be very tricky.